# How to download multiple files in ZIP

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, php-ziparchive

I am trying to read few pdf from a project folder and making them zip and trying to download. I am using ZipArchieve for creating zip file.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/zipfiles/test.zip");
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(path);
        }
        ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(path, ZipArchiveMode.Create);

        var selectedfiles = Directory.GetFiles(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"/pdf"));
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string file in selectedfiles)
        {
            FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(file, FileMode.Open);
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
            fileStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length));

            var demoFile = zip.CreateEntry("test" + i + ".pdf");

            using (var entryStream = demoFile.Open())
            {
                using (var fileToCompressStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
                {
                    fileToCompressStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                    fileToCompressStream.Close();
                }
                entryStream.Close();
            }
            i++;
            fileStream.Close();
        }

        zip.Dispose();

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            file.CopyTo(ms);

        }

        ms.Position = 0;
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(ms); 
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType =
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "file.zip"
        };

        return response;

    }
```

JS Code :

```
<p id="downloadfile">Download File</p>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#downloadfile').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/download",
            success: function (result) {
                var file = new Blob([result], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                a.href = url;
                a.download = 'myfile.zip';
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

After clicking on download now file gets downloaded but when i try to open zip file it gives me error that file is corrupted.

Can please someone suggest where i am wrong.

Comment: don't download files via AJAX. Just give the user a hyperlink to the download URL directly.

Comment: Right but as per my project structure we have to do it via ajax. Do we have any way.

Comment: "as per my project structure we have to do it via ajax"...why? There's nothing about the code above which makes that necessary. Downloading files via ajax makes no logical sense at all anyway - the file data just ends up in a JavaScript variable inside the browser, instead of on the user's disk. So you end up doing like you do above and attempting to create a fake hyperlink and simulating a click event on it to try and force the data to the user's disk using a non-AJAX request.

Comment: So in that case, why bother with this extra layer of code? It achieves nothing useful. Just go straight to the regular non-AJAX request to begin with. It may or may not resolve the file corruption problem but certainly it removes some unnecessary code. P.S. To test whether this is in fact the cause of the corruption, you can of course visit your download URL directly via the browser address bar and see if the file downloads correctly in that scenario.

Comment: Actually i can't call url directly as with each request i send some token to server side and after authentication it works. When we directly hit it token will be missing there and request will not be processed so i am using ajax call because in our main code we will send token in headers. So simply saying i have only this approach

Comment: your code `$.ajax({
            url: "/api/download",` etc does not send any tokens. It makes a simple GET request. I see no difference between this and what a link or button would do.

Comment: I know because  this code is for testing. In actual code we will add token in headers,

Comment: what is the authentication scheme? OAuth, or something else?

Comment: Another test: Change your code temporarily so it also saves the Zip file to the disk on the server. Then log into the server and open the zip file directly from there. Check whether it's corrupt or not. This will narrow down the issue to whether it's your download process, or the ajax code, or simply the creation of the zip file itself which is at fault.

Comment: I verified. zip file saved on disk is opening fine. But when we are downloading using Ajax then file is getting corrupted. I have modified approach as well.

Comment: Ok. Since you mentioned you don't have security on the API currently, visit the download URL directly in your browser to download the file, and see if the result of that is corrupted or not. Then we can narrow it down a bit more.